# AngularJS inject service into module without using variable so it can be minified

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, minify, angularjs

I'm trying to minify my AngularJS JavaScript (using SquishIt).

My module has an injected service as a function argument, like so.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize'], function ($routeProvider) {
...
```

The problem is when I come to minify the code, `$routeProvider` become something like `n` and then AngularJS can't understand it.

I've done something similar with my controller which I think works

```
myapp.controller('MyAppController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$filter', 'storage', function ($scope, $routeParams, $filter, storage) { ... }]);
```

But can't seem to make it work for my module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget it. Figured it out! Very similar to how I achieved the controller, I was just getting overloaded with brackets...

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', 
                           ['ngSanitize'], 
                           ['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) { ... }]);
```